# Why is the graph different after git merge in IDE and terminal?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

[image]

This photo is a graph merged using the IDE’s GUI.

and

[image]

This photo is a graph that was merged directly through the terminal.

Even if you just copy and use the commands executed in the IDE, the results show different graphs like this.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: They look like the same graph except the lines are in a different priority. Try not to worry about this

Comment: It's a good answer, but I don't think it's a good idea for visual references to become difficult. I'd like to know what the problem is.

Comment: Did you merge the branches in the same way? Maybe the difference between the two merge commits is they order of the parents?

Comment: There are two identical branches, and the branch to be merged is completely identical because it was "cloned" through checkout and creation of a new branch.

The merging method is, as mentioned, the difference between the GUI and the terminal. The commands issued at this time are the same.

Comment: Another possible reason : do you have exactly the same ref/branch checked out in the 2 cases? Also we don't see the branches ref in the DAG so it is difficult to have a guess. It could be that in 1st you merged the purple branch in the red one. And in the 2nd,you did the opposite and merges the initially red one in the purple. In term of DAG, the result is the same but maybe not in term of references/branches. To conclude, not enough information to give definitive answer.

Comment: There really is no difference so much that no further explanation is needed.

If you create a copied test branch and merge it using the first method, you will get a clean graph.

If you delete the branch you just tested, create another identical branch, and merge using the second method, you will end up with a messy graph.

Comment: May you make sure you have the same branch or commit checked out when looking at the graph?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Other than the graph shape, everything is the same.

Comment: Then the difference is likely in the arbitrary way your IDE is showing the graph.